# Does a definite integral define a linear functional?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Would $\displaystyle\int_0^1 t^2x(t)\,dt$ be a linear functional? 
For each $x$ in $P$ the function $y$ is defined by $\displaystyle\int_0^1 t^2x(t)\,dt$. I have to show that $y(ax+bz) = ay(x)+by(z)$.  I am confused as to whether or not the $t^2$ term messes it up or not.

Comment: What needs to be true of something to be a linear functional? Make sure you're explicit about the vector space and field involved.

Comment: Nice improvement, but you're still not being explicit. I'm assuming $P$ is the vector space, but *what* is it? Further, what are all these new alphabet soup additions? Who's a vector and who's a scalar? (Note: I'm pretty sure I know what you're talking about, but my point is that if **you** clearly state everything, it's easier for **you** to figure out whether the nonlinear $t^2$ causes $y$ [which is a *terrible* name for an alleged operator, if $x$ and $z$ are vectors, but such is life] to be nonlinear or not).

Comment: P is a field of polynomials in my case... Sorry for the ambiguity. I am still learning about linear algebra :) I believe it is a linear functional, I wrote that y(a1x1+...+anxn)=$\int_0^1 a_1t^2(x_1(t))dt + ... + \int_0^1 a_nt^2(x_n(t))dt$ which equals $a_1\int_0^1 t^2(x_1(t))dt + ... + a_n\int_0^1 t^2(x_n(t))dt$. I am trying to see if that fits the form $a_1y(x_1)+...+a_n(x_n)$

Answer (score 9):

I'm just going to apologize in advance. If there is any lesson to be learned here, it's that

- clearly stating your goals and cast of characters, as well as
- good notation

both help immensely.

---

#### SCENE I

*Enter Vector Space $P$, the space of polynomials with real coefficients and variable $t$, with his servant the Mapmaker.*

**Vector Space $P$:**

 Mapmaker! I had commissioned you to craft a map which, when applied to my vector inhabitants, shall send them linearly to my base field, $\Bbb R$. You have advised the use of a map you call $T$, which takes a vector $f$,  henceforth known as a polynomial, and sends it to the number $$T(f) = \int_0^1 t^2 f(t)~dt.$$

**Mapmaker**

 I have painstakingly crafted the map, sire; so much of my vigor has been spent on its creation that I lie now, infirm. I am quite certain that the map $T$ is linear, but a splendid Space of your nobility deserves proof. Alas, I am unable to provide this with my remaining strength.

**Vector Space $P$:**

 Fret not, for you have served me well. Any student would be lucky to apply himself to your work. I shall send for one now.

*Vector Space $P$'s guards bring a STUDENT from the local university.*

**Vector Space $P$:**

 Ah, a Student! Young man, I require your assistance. My faithful servant Mapmaker has given me a map $T\colon P \to \Bbb R$ that transforms vectors $f$ into numbers $T(f) = \int_0^1 t^2 f(t)~dt$. While I would that he himself were able to, he has not provided me assurance that this map is linear. I myself was never much for cartography; the late Queen was always quick to remind me that I could not tell a linear map from a quadratic form. But enough dithering about.

**STUDENT:**

 Yes my liege, at once.

I shall take your two plainest subjects, the vectors $f$ and $g$, as well as the brutish and arbitrary scalar inhabitants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of the base field $\Bbb R$, to verify that indeed $$T(\alpha f + \beta g) = \alpha T(f) + \beta T(g).$$

The task is easy at first; the map clearly dictates that

$$T(\alpha f + \beta g) = \int_0^1 t^2\big(\alpha f(t) + \beta g(t)\big)~dt,$$

to which a quick distribution yields that we have in fact possessed

$$\int_0^1 \big(\alpha t^2 f(t) + \beta t^2 g(t)\big)~dt$$ all along. I remember dimly that integrals are themselves linear and may be split across sums

$$\int_0^1 \alpha t^2 f(t)~dt + \int_0^1 \beta t^2 g(t)~dt$$ and have their multipliers forced in front

$$\alpha \int_0^1 t^2 f(t)~dt + \beta\int_0^1 t^2 g(t)~dt.$$

This was of course the key insight, for now it is clear to me that this is $\alpha T(f) + \beta T(g)$, that which was to be demonstrated. $\square$

*STUDENT is sent way, while the Court Chaplain arrives to administer the Last Rites to Mapmaker.*

Comment: Very creative and funny +1

Answer (score 2):

The "functional"
$$\phi(x):=\int_0^1 t^2\>x(t)\>dt$$
takes as input a **function** $x:\>t\mapsto x(t)$ and produces as output a **number**. According to the rules about integrals you have learned in Calculus 101 (and have applied a hundred times ever since) it is **obvious** that
$$\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y), \qquad \phi(\lambda x)=\lambda\>\phi(x)$$
for all admissible functions $x$, $y$, and all $\lambda\in{\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(x) = \int_0^1 t^2 x(t) dt$
$$F(\alpha x(t) + \beta y(t)) = \int_0^1t^2(\alpha x(t) + \beta y(t))dt = \int_0^1\alpha t^2x(t) dt + \int_0^1\beta t^2y(t) dt = \alpha \int_0^1t^2x(t)dt + \beta \int_0^1 t^2y(t) dt = \alpha F(x) + \beta F(y)$$

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: typing mistake. put it back.

Comment: Why do you think that «$t^2$ goes away»?

Comment: It doesn't goes way, it stays inside the integral that defines the linear functional.

Answer (score 0):

A linear functional is a linear map from a vector space to its scalar field. As runaround has already shown, the integral is linear (which can be rigorously proven in, say, the Riemann or Lebesgue sense), and thus is a linear functional. The $t^2$ is the integrand and does not have to be linear - you can replace it with any integrable function and your integral will still be a linear functional.